# Trying to build a table of unique values in LUA

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am trying to build a table and add to it at the end each time I get a returned value that is not already in the table. So basically what I have so far is not working at all. I'm new to LUA but not to programming in general.

```
local DB = {}
local DBsize = 0

function test()
  local classIndex = select(3, UnitClass("player")) -- This isn't the real function, just a sample
  local cifound = False

  if classIndex then
    if DBsize > 0 then
      for y = 1, DBsize do
        if DB[y] == classIndex then 
          cifound = True
        end
      end
    end

    if not cifound then 
      DBsize = DBsize + 1
      DB[DBsize] = classIndex
    end
  end
end
```

Then later I'm trying to use another function to print the contents of the table:

```
        local x = 0

        print(DBsize)
        for x = 1, DBsize do
            print(DB[x])
        end
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: [Lua](http://lua.org/about.html#name)*

Comment: You've made a typo: `True` instead of `true` will access the global variable `True` which will be `nil`, hence `cifound` will always be falsy. Note also that you don't need to keep track of `DBsize` yourself - you can simply use `#DB` (as long as your table remains a proper sequence) or `ipairs`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just store a value in the table using your unique value as a key. That way you don't have to check wether a value already exists. You simply overwrite any existing keys if you have it a second time.

Simple example that stores unique values from 100 random values.

```
local unique_values = {}

for i = 1, 100 do
  local random_value = math.random(10)
  unique_values[random_value] = true
end

for k,v in pairs(unique_values) do print(k) end
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work, but one thing you could do (which is an extra step, but works) is that if you're trying to store only unique values, you can create a "table contains" function.

Here's teh gist of what I did:

```
tablecontains(table2process, valuetosearch)
   if next(table2process) == nil then
      return false
   else
      for i = 1, #table2process do
         if table2process[i] == value then
            return true
         end
      end
      return false
   end
end
```

Explanation:

1. Code Checks to see if table you're passing is empty.  If so, return `false`
2. Code then checks every value in the table to ensure the value you're searching for isn't in each element in the table.
   2a. If it DOES exist, the function returns `true`
3. The for loop exits, and an unconditional return `false` is provided (this ensures that if NO value is found in the table, it's safe to be inserted as a unique value).

Usage:
Here's how I use it in my code:

```
if not tablecontains(tabletouse, searchquery) then
   table.insert(tabletouse, searchquery)
end
```

This allows you to only insert what exists within your table beit strings, or other types of values (im using strings!)

Comment: This is both less ergonomic and less efficient than properly using a table as a hash map. There is no reason to use this for strings - using strings as hash map keys is extremely efficient in Lua since all strings are interned.

Comment: Im sure this is true, however, if it's exactly what he's trying to do, this is another way.  Learning how to code is different than learning how to write good code.  He may eventually see the value in using a hash map.  However, if he doesn't code poorly, then learn from his mistakes and see the benefit, he won't really be LEARNING.  he'll instead just be doing what someone online told him to do...

Also, you should show an example of this is it'll help everyone myself included

Comment: Piglet has provided an example; it's pretty much trivial. The author claims to not be new to programming and already shows an almost functional linear search in their question (they just made a typo which causes the found variable to be `nil`, which is falsy, instead of `true`). Linear search still has a raison d'être (e.g. when you have objects with more complex comparisons which would be awkward to hash, or want to maintain a sorted order and only have few elements, etc.), but searching a list of strings usually isn't it (at least in Lua).